# Can someone explain why this code is working?

Tags: node.js, express

So i am using marked (a markdown module) with express, i am not setting the title var or rendering anything and yet the title var is being mutated -i guess- here is the code to my index.js route :

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res, marked){
  marked('Why is this even __working__?.');
};
```

and here is the code to my index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is what i am getting in the browser, although i restarted the app so many times!!:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood the connect/express middleware function signature. You have:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, marked){
```

But that's not right. It's `req, res, next` and there's no `marked` involved. So you aren't rendering markdown, you're passing a string to `next()` which connect/express treat as an error. Your code does this once you remove the misnamed function parameter confusion:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next){
    next('Why is this even __working__?.');
}
```

So connect sees `next` was passed an error string and express render's the default error page with that as the error message.